Is a Pi system comprised of independent events always a lambda system?
If you had a pi-system such that all events are independent, will this always result in a lambda system (so then the pi-lambda theorem can be applied)?

No. For example, why would a $\pi$-system of independent events need to include $\Omega$ or complements?  Indeed, I think we could even have our $\pi$-system comprise a single event, in which case trivially it could not be a $\lambda$-system because it would not include both $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$.  I recommend trying to find more such examples.
Here is another restriction that you might find interesting and could be a good exercise.  Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.  Let $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{F}$ be a $\pi$-system such that any subset of $\mathcal{A}$ is independent with respect to $\mathbb{P}$.  Question: If we additionally assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\lambda$-system, what does this imply about the probabilities for events in $\mathcal{A}$?
